# Criando Schedule pra transferir arquivos CSV do WinSCP pra um FTP

Tags: file-upload, ftp, csv

Preciso transferir arquivos de extensão CSV que estão numa pasta do meu servidor em Linux (acessível via WinSCP pelo Windows) para um FTP. Pra isso, é necessário criar uma schedule que faça essa transferência diariamente.

Encontrei [esse](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule) link que envolve criação e uso de schedules usando WinSCP, mas me ficou meio vago.

O que eu poderia fazer nesse caso?

Answer (score 0):

Você certamente conhece o [PuTTY](http://www.putty.org/), ele tem um utilitário chamado [PSCP](http://www.nber.org/pscp.html), que faz transferência de arquivos via SFTP, ou SSH. Ele pode usar uma sessão criada dentro do PuTTY para a conexão, algo assim:

```
%Path_Putty%\pscp.exe arquivo.csv SESSAO_SSH:/home/user/
```

Isso irá transferir o arquivo.csv para o /home/user/ configurado como SESSAO_SSH no PuTTY.

Crie um BAT, ai é só utilizar o agendador de tarefas do Windows para chamar o BAT.
Configure a sessão com usuário e [chave de acesso SSH](https://diogofernandes.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/conexo-ssh-sem-senha-usando-o-putty/), ai não precisa de senha.

**Um exemplo de BAT**

```
@echo off

:pscp_path
SET PSCP=ERRO
if EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\PuTTY\pscp.exe" SET PSCP="%ProgramFiles%\PuTTY\pscp.exe" 
if EXIST "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PuTTY\pscp.exe" SET PSCP="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PuTTY\pscp.exe" 

if %PSCP% == ERRO goto erro_putty

SET PLINK=ERRO
if EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\PuTTY\plink.exe" SET PLINK="%ProgramFiles%\PuTTY\plink.exe" 
if EXIST "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PuTTY\plink.exe" SET PLINK="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PuTTY\plink.exe" 

if %PLINK% == ERRO goto erro_putty

echo "Enviando arquivos de exportação para servidor"
%PSCP% *.txt CentOS_SSH:/opt/dj/djsystem/integracao
move *.txt processado

echo "Chamando execução do script no servidor linux"
%PLINK% CentOS_SSH sh importa.sh

echo "Copiando arquivos de importação para diretório local"
%PSCP% CentOS_SSH:/opt/integracao/*.txt .

echo "Chamando execução do script de remoção dos arquivos"
%PLINK% CentOS_SSH rm -rf /opt/integracao/*.txt

goto fim

:erro_putty
ECHO Putty não conseguiu instalado.

:fim
```